# describing a sequence of events, does my sentence sounds natural?

Tags: sentence-construction

> As the most affluent ASEAN country, Singapore had undergone
>   industrialization from the 1960s to 1980s and has since undergone
>   de-industrialization.

Does my sentence sound natural?

Comment: Depends on what is to be stressed, if anything.  As written, it does have a flatness to it. If the intent is to stress de-industrialization, perhaps rewrite that portion to set it off (i.e., ...1980s, but has since undergone de-industrialization.)

Comment: It's a bit heavy. What about: **Singapore, the most affluent ASEAN country, underwent industrialisation from the 1960s to the 1980s but has since deindustrialised. ( **but** serves to contrast the two processes and I prefer **the** before 1980s although it's not strictly necessary.)